# How to know which module is the slowest #pytorch

Tags: performance, pytorch, profiling, distributed-computing

Given [a network *(take OpenPCDet as example)*](https://github.com/open-mmlab/OpenPCDet), which runs on distributed GPUs.

How could I know which module costs the most of time during training?

I don't want to manually test each module by

```py
torch.cuda.synchronize()
start = time.time()
result = model(input)
torch.cuda.synchronize()
end = time.time()
```

And `with torch.autograd.profiler.profile(enabled=True) as prof:` only shows me the CPU time:

(which doesn't seem right either, I am not sure I used it properly)

```
-----------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
                         Name    Self CPU %      Self CPU   CPU total %     CPU total  CPU time avg    # of Calls
-----------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
               aten::randperm        28.77%      77.040us        61.28%     164.094us      82.047us             2
                aten::random_        22.25%      59.584us        22.25%      59.584us      29.792us             2
                  aten::empty        21.79%      58.333us        21.79%      58.333us      19.444us             3
                   aten::item        10.91%      29.225us        21.22%      56.807us      28.403us             2
    aten::_local_scalar_dense        10.30%      27.582us        10.30%      27.582us      13.791us             2
          aten::scalar_tensor         4.19%      11.222us         4.19%      11.222us      11.222us             1
                aten::resize_         0.94%       2.507us         0.94%       2.507us       1.253us             2
      aten::is_floating_point         0.85%       2.268us         0.85%       2.268us       1.134us             2
-----------------------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------  ------------
Self CPU time total: 267.761us
```

Answers that only work on a single GPU are also welcomed.

Comment: Have you tried [`torch.profiler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/profiler.html?highlight=profiler#module-torch.profiler)?

Comment: I am using Pytorch 1.8, which shows `AttributeError: module 'torch' has no attribute 'profiler'
`

Comment: I believe [`torch.profiler`](https://pytorch.org/docs/1.9.0/profiler.html?highlight=profiler) was introduced on v1.9.0.

Answer (score 0):

In that case, you'd have to enable cuda on your model, input (`.cuda()` or `.to(device)`) and on the profiler
`with profile(activities=[ProfilerActivity.CPU, profilerActivity.CUDA]) as prof:` as described in the [docu](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/recipes/recipes/profiler_recipe.html)

If you want to profile the training performance, it's also important to call `loss.backward()` inside the profiler context/with block, as the backward pass performance might differ from the forward pass by quite a bit.

Ps.: I also find a bit easier to read the profiler output as a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({e.key:e.__dict__ for e in prof.key_averages()}).T
df[['count', 'cpu_time_total', 'cuda_time_total']].sort_values(['cuda_time_total', 'cpu_time_total'], ascending=False)
```